# Entity Framework and compiled expressions performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

We are using EF for our data access and we have a query like this:

```
Expression<TTable, bool> expression = CreateSomeExpression();
var filter = finalExpression.Compile();
var results = db.t_Table.Where(filter).Select(x=>...);
```

My question is, will EF construct the correct query given a compiled  expression?

As an example, if my table is:

```
t_Table 
( key int,
  value_1 varchar(30),
  value_2 varchar(30)
)
```

And the expression to be compiled is

```
p => p.value_1 = 100
```

will this translate (in EF) to:

```
select * from t_Table where value_1 = 100
```

or will it translate to

```
select * from t_Table
```

followed by a linq query on the results?

Is there a way to check what sql query will actually be called on the DB by EF?

Many thanks in advance,

**Update**

Whilst the accepted answer is 100% correct (and therefore is the accepted answer), the solution to my problem was to simply remove the compilation. Removing that resulted in the correct SQL query with the correct `where clause`.

Comment: 1) try it , 2) yes, `results.ToString()` should give you the SQL

Comment: Take a look at these links. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4703001/1977871
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1412902/1977871 Also if you want to generate run time linq queries, you should look at dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net. This is very versatile.

Comment: @Jcl thanks for your comment. I have tried it and it works but I'm more worried about the performance implications that the results coming back (I don't want a full table results for instance). results.ToString() returns this: `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[CLASS_NAME, RESULT_CLASS_NAME]` (where class_name is the table class name and result_classname is the type of return type of the select)

Comment: If `ToString()` generates `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator...`, this is a clear indication EF will execute part of the query in memory. The expected output is a SQL query string (`SELECT ...`). @Kiril Shlenskiy answer explains that. Just don't do `.Compile()`, use the expression.

Comment: @IvanStoev Great! That did it. Thank you very much for your help. Removing the compile was the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your compiled expression (resulting in a delegate of type `Func<TTable, bool>`) *will*, in fact, cause a full load on the table, i.e.

```
select * from t_Table
```

... and then filter the entities after loading them into memory.

Entity Framework can only translate *expressions* (i.e. `Expression<Func<TTable, bool>>`) into SQL queries. It cannot disassemble a compiled *delegate* (`Func<TTable, bool>`) to subsequently translate it into an SQL query.

This is where overload resolution comes into play. `DbSet<T>` implements both `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`.

- When you use extension methods on `IQueryable<T>` (and most of them accept expression parameters, i.e. `Where<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>>)`), you get your queries executed in the DB engine.
- Whenever you switch over to `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods (i.e. `Where<T>(Func<T, bool>)`), EF has no choice but to load the full set of entities into memory and then iterate over the resulting cache as you would with any other in-memory collection.